# How can I put a variable into my filename?

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I want to copy a `.bat` file. The copy should be in the same path as the original file and have a random number as a name. This is my approach so far:

```
@echo
pause
SET nr = %RANDOM%
xcopy "%cd%\*.bat" "%nr%.bat" /q /y
pause
```

First question: What do I have to do, that the programm creates a `.bat` file with a number in front of the dot? (because now it creates just a `.bat` file without anything in front of the dot...)

Second question: How can I stop the question, if the target is a file or a directory?

Comment: just put a * after the destination...

Comment: Appending a wild-card (`*`, `?`) may work in this situation but can be a bit dangerous as the source name might be copied partially; try the following: `xcopy "file.batch" "new.bat*"` creates a copy named `new.batch`, and `xcopy "file.batch" "new.bat?"` creates a copy named `new.batc`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that the line `SET nr = %RANDOM%` sets a variable called `nr`<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to a random number preceded by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, you actually do not need the interim variable `nr`, you can use `RANDOM` immediately instead.

To avoid the file/directory prompt of `xcopy`, use the `copy` command instead. Regard that this does not support a `/Q` switch. Instead you could use `> nul` to prevent `copy` from displaying something.

You do not need to precede the source `*.bat` with `%CD%\`, as `%CD%` just points to the current working directory, but `*.bat` alone points into that directory anyway.

Finally, I assume by `@echo` you actually mean `@echo off` to suppress command echoes.

So here is the fixed code:

```
@echo off
pause
copy /Y "*.bat" "%RANDOM%.bat" > nul
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

`SET nr = %RANDOM%` creates variable with a trailing space in name: `%nr %` instead of `%nr%` **and** with a leading space in the value.

```
SET nr = %RANDOM%
rem   ↑ ↑           remove spaces
rem                 use following syntax instead
SET "nr=%RANDOM%"
```

You could use

```
xcopy "%cd%\*.bat" "%random%.bat" /q /y
```

but notice that both `%nr%` as well as `%random%` does not change. Following code snippet would be better

```
for /F "delims=" %%G in ( 'dir /b *.bat' ) do (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    xcopy "%%~G" "!random!.bat" /q /y
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

However, [the `%RANDOM%` pseudovariable generates the same "random" number until the clock ticks over another second. (Notice also that the "random" numbers don't look all that random.)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100617-00/?p=13673)

Read the [RANDOM article](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html) as well.